# PKCS12 Certificates

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, cryptography

I want to create pkcs12 private and public key files in c# .net

I want to do this really without having to use makecert.exe or any external programs.

Does anyone know any .net library’s to do this with or any resource so i could create the files myself?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [BouncyCastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/). This question is phrased differently, but on the same subject: [Is it possible to programmatically generate an X509 certificate using only C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770233/is-it-possible-to-programmatically-generate-an-x509-certificate-using-only-c)

Answer (score 0):

[PKIBlackbox package](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/net-pki.php) of our SecureBlackbox product lets you generate and manage certificates in .NET.

Comment: Yes, but what about creating PKCS#12 files?

Comment: @GregS As well. SecureBlackbox supports DER, PEM, PKC#7, PKCS#12, PKCS#8, JKS and NET formats for storing certificates.