# Programmatically import cert into IIS?

Tags: c#, iis, iis-7, ssl, certificate

I have a .pem certificate for SSL, I want to distribute it with my web application in an MSI (has to run on clients' computers). I then need to import it (into some credentials store?) and tell my site bindings to use it.  But how can I do this in code? I've discovered Microsoft.Web.Administration, but not sure where to go from there …

This is in IIS7 btw.

EDIT: The goal here is to have a web application that customers can run on their intranets. It mainly acts as an API for an iPhone app.  (Maybe this isn't the best design but we're locked in now.) So the customer installs the MSI, and voila, they have a web service. Now there needs to be password authentication between the iPhone and the web service; the simplest way seemed to be to do it in https. So I made a self-signed cert.

I'm aware that redistributing a single cert is generally a bad idea, but we're just trying to defeat casual hackers here … this is going to be intranet only and for businesses only, it seems unlikely that anyone is going to be doing anything too crazy, and the API severely restricts the amount of Bad Things you are able to do to the database anyways.

So there we go, the goal is to have password authentication on an intranet web app, with one-click(ish) installation. :-D

Comment: Interesting problem, but do you really want to be re-using an SSL certificate? Even if this is a push-button roll-out for a huge cluster serving your own web app you probably want to be more careful with your certs.

Comment: Note that man-in-the-middle remains possible with a self-signed certificate unless all client phones have this certificate pre-installed in their trusted root certificate stores, before contacting the API.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The answer, dear readers, is this:

```
// Assume 'site' is already set to your site via something like 
// Site site = mgr.Sites.Add(siteName, directory, 443);

X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
store.Open(OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly | OpenFlags.ReadWrite);

// Here, directory is my install dir, and (directory)\bin\certificate.pfx is where the cert file is.
// 1234 is the password to the certfile (exported from IIS)
X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(directory + @"\bin\certificate.pfx", "1234");

store.Add(certificate);

var binding = site.Bindings.Add("*:443:", certificate.GetCertHash(), store.Name);
binding.Protocol = "https";
store.Close();
```

Thanks to this random thread: http://forums.iis.net/t/1163325.aspx

Comment: Don't forget to call mgr.CommitChanges().

Answer (score 1):

You need to narrow down your question. What is the certificate used for (exactly)?

If your certificate is used for client-side authentication (to authenticate the client on the server), then distributing it with your application makes such authentication plain useless, as you would be disclosing the secret key.

If you need to validate the server's certificate (and you've been given server's certificate or certificate chain in your PEM file), then this could work, but why would you need to install the certificate to the certificate store?

You should note, that PEM format is not natively supported by Windows or .NET libraries so you need to convert it to PFX before deployment, and then import a PFX or just create a store in memory based on PFX (you will find plenty of information by looking for PFX or PKCS#12 on StackOVerflow).

Upd: it would be a better approach to generate the certificate each time you install the application and let the user have their own certificate (eg. it's possible that they already have a valid certificate for their web site).

Comment: Sorry, 2am vagueness ; )  Edited above.

Comment: Hmm good point; although I guess you are always going to be stuck with that self-signed certificate confirmation dialog in the browser?  I am down for that approach... but how do I do it in code?  (I'm a Windows programming noob :-D)  EDIT: The idea here is that people installing this software don't know computers, so if this was all automated that would be best.

Comment: @Dave to avoid browser confirmation the user needs to obtain the certificate from one of known certificate authorities (globalsign, comodo, thawte, verisign etc.). As for certificate generation - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770233/is-it-possible-to-programmatically-generate-an-x509-certificate-using-only-c and also our Secureblackbox product among other functions offers full PKI infrastructure support including certificate generation and signing (http://www.eldos.com/sbb/desc-pki.php).