# c# create x509 certificate in code

Tags: c#, certificate, x509

i want to create a x509 certificate in code behind. So far as i knew the only way to do this is to use [makecert Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfsktky3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), the thing is that i dont want to make mannually in command prompt cert but in code. Is there a way to do this? I can't find any article or example how to do this. Can anyone reference me to somewhere?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770233/

Answer (score 0):

You can use BouncyCastle or our SecureBlackbox for certificate generation. Much easier and more flexible than calling anything from command line.